# How to split a long HTML file into separate inter-linked pages like page 1, page 2, page 3

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webforms

have a requirement where i need to split large HTML page into multiple pages based on the condition if height of the div tag is more than 700pixels in height.

I can also split page based on number of words.

Following example splits the page based on the HTML tag while i need to achive same either based on div height or no. of words

example http://splity.sourceforge.net/

I need to do this for asp.net using c#. I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction as i could not find much related to same so far

[image]

information:- I store Article as rich text with all the HTML tag in the database field, so i am looking for a way to break page using jquery if div height reaches certain height & breaks it as show in image above

Comment: What is the question?  Also, we are not your research assistant.

Comment: Why is it tagged with both c# and jQuery? Are you looking for a client- or serverside solution?

Comment: Doing it by number of words isn't a good solution because of screen size etc.  Dimensions is better, but what you're really talking about is building a responsive site...

Comment: @Johan, Anything that works either C# or jQuery. I think if it is possible then both need to be used

Comment: @Alan, I have added an example image i want to limit the article text certain height & dont want the Page to grow in height with content. so i need to break the page into multiple pages if Content DIV reaches certain height.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        var $html = $(data);

        var $articles = $html.find('div.article'); //find the divs that you want to make use of

        $articles.each(function(){
            if($(this).height() > 200) //filter the articles based on your conditions
                //do stuff with the filetered alticles
        });
    }
});
```